Strange behaviour on Random Forest Classifier
I've build two identical rf_classifier, like so:
rf_PB = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=800, 
 min_samples_split = 10,
 min_samples_leaf = 4,
 max_features  = 'sqrt',
 max_depth = 50,
 bootstrap = True, random_state=59)

And trained with two identical datasets but with 2 different target variable (the sell or not sell of a specific product).
To me, they are both behaving well, the first one with 78% accuracy and the second one with 84%.
Both are trained with like 13.5k obs, 7k class 1, 6.5k class 0.
The problem is that the first one behaves that the probability distributions of an observation to be 1 is quite well distribuited (i'm using predict_proba to create 3 different classes at the end), the second one instead tends to predict pretty much everything as 1, even if the training set is well balanced and the accuracy is 84%. But when I use the fitted model to predict new clients, almost all of them are predicted as 1, with a probability > 0.8.
I don't understand why my algorithm is behaving like this and the business, after being very happy for the results of the first one, that allowed us to focus on like 1000 clients predicted as 1 for the first product to sell, now are facing that like 120.000 clients are predicted as 1 for the second product, and they are assuming that it's my fault that I didn't train the algorithm well.
The thing that I don't understand is that by computing the correlation with the target column, the higher one has 0.5 of correlation, but in the 120.000 obs given almost all of them had that column = 0, so I don't understand why they are predicted with a 0.99 probability of 1.
The (simple) code:
X = df.drop(columns=['ValoreTrainingAI'])
y = df['ValoreTrainingAI']




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)


rf_PB = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=800, 
 min_samples_split = 10,
 min_samples_leaf = 4,
 max_features  = 'sqrt',
 max_depth = 50,
 bootstrap = True, random_state=59)


rf_PB.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred_proba = rf_PB.predict_proba(X_test)


This doesn't strike me as a code problem, so might get better answers at datascience.SE or stats.SE; but it probably needs some more details there too, e.g. a histogram of the predicted probabilities, more clarity about the target(s), maybe some information about the features used, etc.

(The DS.SE post, for interested folks: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/129085/55122)
